# Cordova iOS app is running with iOS 7 style

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap, testflight

My Cordova app is built with phonegapbuild cli 9 and all plugins are up-todate. App is installed via TestFlight on iPhone iOS 12. My problem is that app is running in iOS 7 style and everything like status bar and keyboard are enlarged and displayed blury.
I tried wkwebview but made no difference.

Comment: You need a launch storyboard.

Comment: thanks. problem solved